# What is the most correct way to round up a fraction?

Tags: approximation, rounding-error

Say we have two rational numbers.

$a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$

If c is defined as:

$c = \tfrac{a}{b}$

What is the best (most correct) way to round up the fraction to two decimal places?

1. By round $a$ and $b$ first
2. By diving $a$ and $b$ as they are, and then rounding the result.

Example:

Say $a=1.541$ and $b=2.317$

We can either get:

1. $c=\frac{1.54}{2.32} = 0.6637$, and by rounding to two decimal places, $c=0.66$

OR

2. $c=\frac{1.541}{2.317} = 0.6650$, so by rounding to two decimal places, $c=0.67$

Comment: Method $1$ isn't really well defined.  After all $\frac {1.541}{2.317}=\frac {1541}{2317}$ which, I'm assuming, you wouldn't round at all, yes?

Comment: If there is an even digit before $5$, we do not increase it, i.e., in (2.), the correctly rounded value of $c$ is $0.66$ and NOT $0.67$

Comment: @BarryCipra  Yes, but I don't see how to do that by rounding the numerator and denominator since, unless I am misreading, equivalent forms of the rational number would then lead to different roundings.

Comment: @AdityaSingh, in writing $0.6650$, the OP *truncated* the decimal result $0.6650841\ldots$, so rounding up is actually appropriate for the fraction itself, if not for the truncated approximation.

Comment: @lulu the fractional value is $0.66508416\ldots$. `@Barry`, I would have gone with $.67$ too, but in the post, (s)he has truncated the decimal and is rounding according to that.

Comment: @AdityaSingh  Yes, thanks. I mistyped the fraction.  But the OP has not specified a rounding convention...not everybody follows the "even/odd" rule.  And the OP has not stated whether they prefer $.66$ or $.67$ as the answer

Comment: @BarryCipra  Yeah, my value was wrong (mistyped the numerator) and yours is correct.

Comment: Hi, I prefer the 2nd option. It seems to me "more correct" mathematically. The first answer is obtained by applying the rounding for two times; (1) for numerator and denominator before dividing them, and (2) for the final result. But for the second answer the rounding is applied only to the final answer.

Comment: @AWanderingMind, it's a lot to read but you might take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures and the link there to "significance arithmetic."